# How do you affect a specific element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(Thank you to anyone kind enough to help)

I'm having trouble using the jQuery hover method on a single instance of an element with a class name shared by multiple elements

Below I have provided my code:

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="c_box">
    <div class="img">
        <svg hieght="0" width="0">
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="svgPath">
              <circle stroke="#000000" cx="125" cy="235" r="125"></circle>
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="250" height="230"></rect>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
        </svg>
        <div class="rectangle">
          <div class="semi_circle"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="text">Painting</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="c_box">
    <div class="img">
        <svg hieght="0" width="0">
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="svgPath">
              <circle stroke="#000000" cx="125" cy="235" r="125"></circle>
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="250" height="230"></rect>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
        </svg>
        <div class="rectangle">
          <div class="semi_circle"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="text">Painting</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  $(".container").hover(function(){
    $(".c_box").animate({top: "-37px" }, 250);
    $(".rectangle").delay(250).animate({right: "50px" }, 250);
    $(".text").delay(450).animate({left: "69px" }, 150);
    $(".triangle").delay(450).animate({top: "-20px" }, 150);
  },
    function(){
    $(".text").animate({left: "-105px" }, 150);
    $(".rectangle").delay(150).animate({right: "280px" }, 150);
    $(".c_box").delay(250).animate({top: "-360px" }, 250);
    $(".triangle").delay(450).animate({top: "0px" }, 150);
    }
  );
});$(document).ready(function (){

  $(".container").hover(function(){
    $(".c_box").animate({top: "-37px" }, 250);
    $(".rectangle").delay(250).animate({right: "50px" }, 250);
    $(".text").delay(450).animate({left: "69px" }, 150);
    $(".triangle").delay(450).animate({top: "-20px" }, 150);
  },
    function(){
    $(".text").animate({left: "-105px" }, 150);
    $(".rectangle").delay(150).animate({right: "280px" }, 150);
    $(".c_box").delay(250).animate({top: "-360px" }, 250);
    $(".triangle").delay(450).animate({top: "0px" }, 150);
    }
  );
});
```

The code works fine, however, both the divs with the class 'container' are effected. Ideally i would like to only affect one div at a time (the one the mouse interacts with)

I'm familiar with the '$(this)' selector. Although, I have know idea if it's applicable in this case.

Comment: it is what you need in this case.. use this context to tell which element made the action

Comment: use stopPropagation(); on the elements you don't want to be affected

Comment: `$(".container")[0]` and the like?

Comment: You're almost there! `$(this)` is the correct answer - you just need to modify the elements you're animating in the hover function like so: `$('.c_box')` would become `$(this).find('.c_box')` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target the `.c_box`, `.rectangle`, `.text`, `.triangle` of the current `.container`. The current container can be targeted using `$(this)`.

```
$(function () {
  $('.container').hover(function () {
    var $currentContainer = $(this);
    var $cBox = $currentContainer.find('.c_box');
    var $rectangle = $currentContainer.find('.rectangle');
    var $text = $currentContainer.find('.text');
    var $triangle = $currentContainer.find('.triangle');

    $cBox.animate({ top: '-37px' }, 250);
    $rectangle.delay(250).animate({ right: '50px' }, 250);
    $text.delay(450).animate({ left: '69px' }, 150);
    $triangle.delay(450).animate({ top: '-20px' }, 150);
  }, function () {
    var $currentContainer = $(this);
    var $cBox = $currentContainer.find('.c_box');
    var $rectangle = $currentContainer.find('.rectangle');
    var $text = $currentContainer.find('.text');
    var $triangle = $currentContainer.find('.triangle');

    $text.animate({ left: '-150px' }, 150);
    $rectangle.delay(150).animate({ right: '280px' }, 150);
    $cBox.delay(250).animate({ top: '-360px' }, 250);
    $triangle.delay(450).animate({ top: '0' }, 150);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dork, This has resolved my issue.

All the best - Krayz